# HTTPRequest import error in gwt

Tags: gwt

I am learning GWT and trying to create a sample application. GWT version is 2.5.1. In the `EntryPint` I have this code

```
HTTPRequest.asyncGet
  (GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "person.xml",
       new ResponseTextHandler() {
         public void onCompletion(String responseText) {
           // code goes here
         }
       }
```

I do have the import for `HTTP`.

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.HTTPRequest;
```

But this fails to import and the error looks like -

```
[javac] import com.google.gwt.user.client.HTTPRequest;
[javac]                                  ^
[javac] symbol  : variable HTTPRequest
[javac] location: class com.google.gwt.sample.client.TalkToServer
[javac]     HTTPRequest.asyncGet
```

Also, I added this line in gwt.xml file

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.http.HTTP'/>
```

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 3):

`com.google.gwt.user.client.HTTPRequest` had been deprecated since GWT 1.5 (more than 5 years ago) and has been removed in GWT 2.1.0 (3 years ago).

Use `com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder` instead.

Comment: Ok, that is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

To get the XML from the server, try something like this:

```
    final RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, “person.xml“);
    builder.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {
        @override
        public void onError(final Request request, final throwable exception) {
            // handle Exception
        }
        @override
        public void onResponseRecieved(final Request request, final Response response) {
            // handle Reponse  - use response.getText() to get the response text
        }
    };
```

Use the GWT XML-Handling to parse your XML. You will find information here:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsXML.html

Hope that helps